# One action can have two method?

Tags: java, asp.net, jsp, struts2, action

in asp.net, one controller can have many ActionResult return many ways.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

how to do it in Java Struts2, one Action have only one execute that able to return one way.

Comment: [`Action#execute()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/) returns a String, whichever String you want. That is the framework you chose, which uses a single method. If you want a different API, use a different framework (Spring, Tapestry, GWT).

Comment: In Struts2 the Action is a controller it may have as many actions as you want, the same is for results per action. So it multiply the possibility of the action to return a single result. How they are executed depends on mapping URLs to methods of the Action. If not mapped the method but mapped the class then execute method used by default.

Comment: Just read about action configuration: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/action-configuration.html.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one `Index` in your example, just like there's only one `execute` in an S2 action.

Actions may, however, have an arbitrary number of methods. Those methods may be called in a number of ways, including configuration via annotations, XML, or by using the [Convention plugin](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Convention%20Plugin) or [REST plugins](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html).

In your example you don't show one method returning multiple ways, you show multiple actions returning multiple ways, which is supported under Struts 2 in similar ways.

Comment: actually i figure a little out. you mean one method in c# public ActionResult Contact() correspond to one Action class in Struts2.0, so in this c# controller, there actually need 3 Action class in Struts2.0? is there any possible we make fewer class to see simplier

Comment: @user2339970 No, that's not what I meant. I meant more or less what I said: you can have as many methods in an action as you want. How they're called/declared depends.

Comment: I wish "Action Class" was defined in struts documentation because in an action based framework _everything_, well every request is an action. It may have a user defined action class, it might not... the word "action" sounds like smurf at times, we get what is meant but when people are learning it isn't that clear. Read Coman C's comment for an example of this!